# C# and PostgreSQL INSERT INTO

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have this:

```
NpgsqlConnection c = new NpgsqlConnection(conx.getConexion());
c.Open();
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("Insert into \"Marca\" (\"NombreMarca\") values ('" + cbMarca.Text + "')", c);
c.Close();
```

And the table is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE idmarca
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 2147483647
  START 10
  CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE "Marca"
( "idMarca" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('idmarca'::regclass),
  "NombreMarca" character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PKMarca" PRIMARY KEY ("idMarca" ),
  CONSTRAINT "UNombreMarca" UNIQUE ("NombreMarca" )
);
```

The problem is, when I try to insert into the table, for some reason nothing happens. That's on a try - catch, so no exceptions are being generated from the query.
`cbMarca` is a combobox. The connection with the database is already tested.

Also, this works:

```
cbMarcaB.Items.Clear();
DataTable dt = cons.Select("Select \"NombreMarca\" From \"Marca\" Order by \"NombreMarca\"");
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         cbMarcaB.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["NombreMarca"]);
     }
```

So I don't know what the problem is ...

Comment: Have you checked resulting query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be using the NpgsqlDataAdapter to do an insert rather use the NpgsqlCommand see the example below [found here](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/exampleprograms.html).

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO npdata VALUES (@key, @ndata)";
NpAdapter.InsertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

NpParam = NpAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@key", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text);
NpParam.SourceColumn = "key";
NpParam.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;

NpParam = NpAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ndata", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint);
NpParam.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
NpParam.SourceColumn = "ndata";
```

Comment: I saw that, but theres no NpAdapter in the library. Thats why i was using DataAdapter. What reference do i have to import to be able to use the Adapter?

Comment: Sorry, at the top of his code, 
    private NpgsqlDataAdapter NpAdapter;